# change p content with text file one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm coding my first website, now I'm trying to change a p content with the content of some text files, which contains long descriptions of what my site is about, actually I've tried many ways, like httprequest(), FileReader() and jquery get, but actually I haven't managed it,because I was running it locally and probably because of the wrong file position,  so i created a new small code in witch I tried jquery get, I ran it on "web server for chrome" but it doesn't work.

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div><h2 id="demo">Lets change this text</h2></div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
<script       
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
    $.get("hello.txt",function(data){
    getElementById('demo').innerText= data;
  });
 }
</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

when I load it, the p and the button are displayed, but when I click the button nothing happens; the .html and the .txt files are in the same folder.
I'have been stuck on it for many days, please help, and don't mark it as duplicate.

any help is appreciate.

Comment: Could you put up ur code in JSFIddle? it would easy for us to debug your issue. If your .txt file has some sensitive content then put a dummy content and share link with us.

Comment: the code is only the one above, anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/tvgsx45g/#&togetherjs=SUJmCrpHql

Comment: thank you guys, all the answer of yours works.

Comment: well, all the answer are right, but the ajax one is the cooler...

Comment: @Muccagelato Cool! I have updated my Plunker if you want to reference from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this [out](http://plnkr.co/edit/sDptU9vLOy8QpcHiRzfB?p=preview)

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
    $.get("hello.txt",function(data){
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= data;
  });
 }

</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <div><h2 id="demo">Lets schange this text</h2></div>

    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDocWithHttp()">Change Content from Http request</button>
```

Using AJAX:

```
function loadDocWithHttp() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "hello.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will use it for future refernce

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
     function loadDoc() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "hello.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success : function (result) {
                        $("#demo").html(result);
                    }
                });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all do one change in your script as mentioned below

```
function loadDoc() {
    $.get("hello.txt",function(data){
        $('#demo').html(data);
    });
}
```

For that button you have to bind click with delegation method `on()`

```
$(document).on('click','<your_button_selector>', function(){
    alert("hello") // replace and put your code here
});
```

Good Luck..!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function loadDoc() {
    $.get("hello.txt",function(data){
    document.getElementById('demo').text= data;
  });
 }
```

or

```
function loadDoc() {
    $.get("hello.txt",function(data){
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= data;
  });
 }
```

You can use jQuery Ajax function. The `error` attribute will be helpful to get the exception:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "./seeds/hello.txt",
            async: false,
            success: function (data){
                pageExecute.fileContents = data;
            },
            error: function (e){
                //error print
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`getElementById('demo').innerText= data;`

change to below line.

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerText= data;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.can u browse http://url/hello.txt in your browner?

2.open the developer tools, does any errors show?

3.getElementById have to be used under document Object